# Multi-threaded image convolution/pooling-python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multithreading, image

This multi-threaded code takes an array of 3d images and applies the convolution function with padding, stride, pad values .. as parameters and same applies for creating pooling layers. I need suggestions on how to improve performance and maybe get rid of the for loops used(if that is possible).

Use this photo `tiger.jpeg` for producing the example in the code.

[image: tiger.jpeg]

**Code:**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import perf_counter
import numpy as np
import cv2


def pad_image(image, pad_width, values, mode='img_arr'):
    """
    Add a pad(border) of a given width and value to the image.
    Args:
        image: Image array or a single image.
        pad_width: Width of the pad layer.
        values: Value of the pad layer.
        mode: A string representation of the input
            'img_arr': Array of images.
            'img': A single image.

    Return:
        numpy array of padded images or a padded image.
    """
    if mode == 'img_arr':
        return np.array(list(map(lambda x: cv2.copyMakeBorder(
            x, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=values), image)))
    if mode == 'img':
        return cv2.copyMakeBorder(
            image, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=values)


def calculate_size(image_shape, kernel_shape, pad_width, stride):
    """
    Calculate size of the output after one pass of the convolution function.
    Args:
        image_shape: Input shape.
        kernel_shape: Convolution filter shape.
        pad_width: Width of the pad layer.
        stride: The number of pixels a kernel moves.
    Return:
        height, width, channels.
    """
    height, width, channels = image_shape
    kernel_size = kernel_shape[1]
    output_height = int((height - kernel_size + 2 * pad_width) / stride) + 1
    output_width = int((width - kernel_size + 2 * pad_width) / stride) + 1
    output_channels = kernel_shape[-1]
    return output_height, output_width, output_channels


def partition_image(image, stride, pad_width, pad_values, kernel_size):
    """
    Prepare image to apply the convolution function.
    Args:
        image: numpy array containing image data.
        stride: The number of pixels a kernel moves.
        pad_width: Width of the pad layer.
        pad_values: Value of the pad layer.
        kernel_size: Size of the convolution filter.

    Return:
        R, G, B partitioned numpy arrays.
    """
    partitions = []
    padded = pad_image(image, pad_width, pad_values, 'img')
    height, width, channels = padded.shape
    red = padded[..., 0]
    green = padded[..., 1]
    blue = padded[..., 2]
    for item in red, green, blue:
        item = [item[
               h: h + kernel_size, w: w + kernel_size]
               for h in range(0, height - kernel_size + 1, stride)
               for w in range(0, width - kernel_size + 1, stride)]
        partitions.append(np.array(item))
    return partitions


def convolve_image(image, kernel, bias, pad_width, stride, pad_values):
    """
    Apply convolution function to an image.
    Args:
        image: numpy image nd array.
        kernel: Convolution filter.
        bias: A scalar.
        pad_width: Width of the pad layer.
        stride: The number of pixels a kernel moves.
        pad_values: Value of the pad layer.

    Return:
        Convolution output, cache.
    """
    channel = 0
    target_height, target_width, target_channels = calculate_size(
        image.shape, kernel.shape, pad_width, stride)
    output = np.zeros((target_height, target_width, target_channels))
    red_part, green_part, blue_part = partition_image(
        image, stride, pad_width, pad_values, kernel.shape[0])
    red_kernel, green_kernel, blue_kernel = kernel[..., 0], kernel[..., 1], kernel[..., 2]
    for img_col, kl_color in zip([red_part, green_part, blue_part], [red_kernel, green_kernel, blue_kernel]):
        product = img_col * kl_color
        addition = np.array(list(map(np.sum, product)))
        addition += bias
        addition = addition.reshape(target_height, target_width)
        output[..., channel] = addition
        channel += 1
    cache = image, kernel, bias
    return output, cache


def convolve_image_arr(img_arr, kernel, bias, pad_width, stride, pad_values, threads):
    """
    Convolve an array of images.
    Args:
        img_arr: numpy array of images.
        kernel: Convolution filter.
        bias: A scalar.
        pad_width: Width of the pad layer.
        stride: The number of pixels a kernel moves.
        pad_values: Value of the pad layer.
        threads: Number of parallel threads.

    Return:
        Convolved image array, caches.
    """
    z, caches, current_img, total_images = [], [], 0, img_arr.shape[0]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        future_output = {executor.submit(
            convolve_image, img, kernel, bias, pad_width, stride, pad_values):
                         img for img in img_arr}
        for future_item in as_completed(future_output):
            convolved_img, cache = future_item.result()
            print(f'Convolved image {current_img} out of {total_images} ... done')
            z.append(convolved_img)
            caches.append(cache)
            current_img += 1
        return z, caches


def pool_image(image, window_size, stride, mode):
    """
    Create a pooling layer to the image.
    Args:
        image: numpy image nd array.
        window_size: Size of the sliding window/kernel.
        stride: The number of pixels a kernel moves.
        mode: Calculation mode
            'max': Window will be maximized.
            'avg': Window will be averaged.

    Return:
        Output layer, image.
    """
    channel, result = 0, 0
    target_height, target_width, target_channels = calculate_size(
        image.shape, (window_size, window_size), 0, stride)
    output = np.zeros((target_height, target_width, target_channels))
    red_part, green_part, blue_part = partition_image(image, stride, 0, 0, window_size)
    for img in red_part, green_part, blue_part:
        if mode == 'max':
            result = np.array(list(map(np.max, img)))
        if mode == 'avg':
            result = np.array(list(map(np.mean, img)))
        result = result.reshape(target_height, target_width)
        output[..., channel] = result
        channel += 1
    return output, image


def pool_image_arr(img_arr, window_size, stride, mode, threads):
    """
    Create a pooling layer to a numpy array of images.
    Args:
        img_arr: numpy array of images.
        window_size: Size of the sliding window/kernel.
        stride: The number of pixels a kernel moves.
        mode: Calculation mode
            'max': Window will be maximized.
            'avg': Window will be averaged.
        threads: Number of parallel threads.

    Return:
        Pooling layer output, images.
    """
    output, current_img, total_images = [], 1, img_arr.shape[0]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        future_output = {executor.submit(pool_image, img, window_size, stride, mode): img
                         for img in img_arr}
        for future_item in as_completed(future_output):
            layered_img, img = future_item.result()
            print(f'Layered image {current_img} out of {total_images} ... done')
            output.append(layered_img)
            current_img += 1
        return np.array(output), img_arr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = perf_counter()
    tiger = cv2.imread('tiger.jpeg')
    tigers = np.array([tiger for _ in range(50)])
    kl = np.random.randn(3, 3, 3)
    pa, st = 1, 1
    b = np.random.randn()
    p_values = 0
    z, cc = convolve_image_arr(tigers, kl, b, pa, st, p_values, 10)
    t2 = perf_counter()
    print(f'Time: {t2 - t1} seconds.')
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using multithreading over multiprocessing here? Can you share some information on the current performance?

Comment: @AMC no, there is not, do you suggest multiprocessing is a better choice? why?

Comment: @AMC You can check the performance by changing this line `tigers = np.array([tiger for _ in range(50)])` increase 50 to higher values and see for yourself

Comment: _do you suggest multiprocessing is a better choice? why?_ Yes, in Python threads are almost always used for IO only, for a few different reasons. There are plenty resources on the subject, which can explain things far better than I can.